# Make Qt5 connect style work in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

I want to port an app (small to mid size) from Qt5 to Qt4. Do I need to manually rewrite all the connects (which currently use the new Qt5 style)?

I'm looking for an alternative (easy) approach :)

Comment: Why porting to Qt4? Because building Qt5 in a Raspberry Pi it's very time consuming.

Comment: @KcFnMi can't you cross compile Qt 5 for Pi and then copy it over, could be faster (_disclaimer_: I do not have experience with cross compilation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to instrument `connect` to dump the old-style syntax equivalent at runtime, with file name and line number, and use that to replace the new-style connects with old-style connects.

By instrumenting connect I mean replacing the `connect` with `myConnect` macro using search-and-replace, and writing your own `myConnectImpl` that executes `QObject::connect` and then synthesizes the old-style connect and dumps it. To convert method pointers to method indexes, use `mataobject->static_metacall(object, QMetaObject::IndexOfMethod, args)` for the metaobject of a given class and then [proceed up the superclasses](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/blob/master/questions/metaproxy-32612309/main.cpp#L63) till you reach `QObject`.

You do have to understand some implementation details to pull that off. Perhaps [this answer-in-progress](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/blob/master/questions/metaproxy-32612309/main.cpp) will provide some inspiration.

Comment: Or a Clang plugin. Still feels... hacky?

Comment: @peppe Anything that is quicker than a fully manual job would probably be worth it :) clang plugin would also work, but is a bit more code perhaps - I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, yes. But you can always make a little script to go fileby file and change them.

Comment: It will be a big script. Because you need to handle not only method types, but also static_cast